# Bash script log file display to screen continuously

Tags: linux, bash, logging

I am creating an application that writes to a log file, and I need to know how in Linux / Bash to continuously display the log file to the screen (updating the screen with every new line put into the log).

So as an example, lets say I want to push a running log of `apache/error.log` to the screen (ssh terminal) continuously updating.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45626/output-file-contents-while-they-change

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Try the tail command:

```
tail -f filename
```

Comment: vu well now I feel like an idiot.  I use the tail command all the time, (just not with the -f parameter).  man tail would have been my friend.  Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!!  Will accept the answer when it allows (9min)

Comment: vu this is even better than writing a script :) (although could be added to a script I suppose as well)

Comment: with the option `--follow=name` you'll be sure to keep the content of the log file displayed even if the file has been rotated/recreated by a cron job.

Comment: @aaron Just a note since you mentioned you are creating the application, and then plan to tail the log, just be careful to understand that just because you have written a line in the application doesn't mean the line has shown up in the log since the output may be buffered.

Answer (score 32):

Another solution is

```
 less +F filename
```

or just `less filename` and typing "F" into it (pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>). It can be better than `tail`, because it allows you to cancel continuous printing temporary, go backward to look something and reenable it with "F" (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>) again

Comment: I am taking notes, thats a great alternative!

Comment: Plus, it can truncate long lines **out of the box** for you with the `-S` flag, while allowing you to scroll left/right through them. Superior to the `tail -f file.log | cut ...` method.

Comment: I don't understand the key combo. First press `F` then `Shift`? Or press them simultaneously? I tried but it made no difference.

Comment: becko, thank you, just type "F" (Shift + F) - press and hold Shift, then press f, then release both keys. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 11):

The watch command can also be of use.

```
watch tail logfile
```

Would show you the last 5 lines of the log file.  It can be extended to any command which prints stuff to stdout.

Yes, using `tail -f` is the traditional solution, but depending on what you are trying to do, this might work better.

Comment: more notes.  Linux = a million ways to skin the same cat :) thank you

Answer (score 6):

`ssh {remotehost} tail -n0f {logfile}`

This will give you zero lines initially, and continuously print any new lines that appear in the file.

Answer (score 6):

You can also:

```
less filename.txt
and press 'F'
```

has one plus - you can anytime CTRL-C and scroll back in log and start watching again with the 'F'.

Comment: I am so amazed at the response times on the questions, I tried answsering a couple questions and there are many people that are faster on the refresh button around here than I :)  Thanks for the answer / tip as well